# How to set the Value of a Record Set in Amazon route 53

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I'm trying to configure a custom domain using Amazon route 53, using [these](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/CreatingNewDNS.html#NewDNSAddRecords)
instructions provided by Amazon. For the "Value" field (see image below), it says I have to insert a string that contains the information required by the selected type, but it doesn't say what type I have to enter, and what that value would be. In the image below, it shows the default A-LPv4 address, but I changed it to CNAME and then entered my domain name `example.com` (error) and `www.example.com`

In both cases, the error said

```
RRSet of type CNAME with DNS name example.com. is not permitted at apex in zone example.com
```

I can't leave that field blank either.  How do you configure this section?

Note, the example shown in the image appears to use ip address, but I'm not sure which ones you're supposed to use. These numbers (from the Delegation Set)are not permitted format

```
ns-1XXX.awsdns-XX.co.uk
ns-3XX.awsdns-XX.com
ns-5XX.awsdns-XX.net
ns-1XXX.awsdns-XX.org
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The root (example.com) cannot be a CNAME because it breaks [RFC 1034](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1034.html), which states

> If a CNAME RR is present at a node, no other data should be present;
>   this ensures that the data for a canonical name and its aliases cannot
>   be different.

However, Route53 provides a proprietary extension known as an [`Alias` resource record](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/CreatingAliasRRSets.html) that allows this. Choose A record for the Type, choose the Yes radio button next to Alias, then choose an ELB or another record from the same zone as the value.